How to apply bricksschema on live telemetry?
i am trying to understand on how to build a hardware agnostic remote monitoring solution, one of the suggestions is to use brick schema to define the relationships (ontologies) of the equipment available in your premise. I understand there are several tools for building the ontology, however what i do not understand is that how can one apply this logical representation onto the incoming data from multiple hardware controllers each following its protocol for communication. Could someone please help shed some light on this?
